# Unable to think about property of an infinite bounded subset of Real line.

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

I am trying some questions of a qualifying exam and I am unable to think about how to think about this question.

Question is -> Let X which is subset of Real Numbers be an infinite countable bounded subset of Real numbers. Then which one is true.

(1) X cannot be compact. 
(2) X may be closed.

By bolzano wierestrauss property X must have a limit point but how to be sure whether it lies in the set X itself or not.

Also, regarding compactness I am unable to think anything.

Can someone please help how to approach this question.

Comment: $\{ {1 \over n} \} _{n \in \mathbb{Z} \setminus \{0\} } \cup \{0\}$. This is compact & closed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, note that closed would imply compact by the Heine-Borel theorem, so you only need to find out if $X$ can be closed or not.

The thing is, it can be either. Consider for example $\{1/n : n \in \mathbb{N}\}$ and $\{0\} \cup \{1/n : n \in \mathbb{N} \}$. The first one is not closed, while the second one is.